# Bootstrap Tabs not working but code is looking fine

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

This is first time that my bootstrap tabs is not working my code is simple and everything looking OK but on my system it's not working.

Following is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tabs </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" title="no title">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
       </ul>

       <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">home</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">profile</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">messages</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">settings</div>
       </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add data-toggle="tab" to anchor**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ENG">
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags always come first-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title Page</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" class="nav-link active">Active 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" class="nav-link">Active 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#message" class="nav-link">Active 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" class="nav-link">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">home</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">profile</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="message">messages</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">settings</div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script><!-- Tether for Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```